# Using Eventbridge to trigger Glue job but with delay

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, events, aws-lambda

I want to create an Eventbridge rule which triggers after certain number of files are uploaded into the S3 bucket. For ex: Consider a certain prefix in bucket is empty(bucket/folder/[empty]), the user needs to upload 5 files. Only after those five files are uploaded can the Eventbridge be triggered. I tried searching for rule pattern, but unable to find anything related to this. Currently using

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["test-bucket-for-event"]
    },
    "object": {
      "key": [{
        "prefix": "folder/Latest/"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Can i mention like, numbers here, like using greater than 5 etc.
Or how to configure that.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't do this that way because each object will have its corresponding event.

Comment: There is no such functionality. Instead, you will need to trigger an AWS Lambda function. Then, the code in the Lambda function will need to either count the number of files, or check that all files have been uploaded.

Comment: Let us consider your idea, i was thinking of adding s3 trigger, so whenever files are added to s3, the lambda function is triggered. So to count, how can i wait till 5 files are there. Or check all files are uploaded, how can this be done. Ex. my file names would be test_fact_010822.xlsx, test_geo_010822.xlsx, etc. i have five files with certain naming prefix (test_geo_) then date and ext. I cannot predefine these in the function as it changes based on date.

Comment: I have solved it. I just counted and used trigger after a certain limit is reached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Lambda function which is used to trigger glue job after certain number of files are created

```
import json
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event,context):
    bucket = "bucket-name"
    folder = "Folder/Subfolder/"
    objs = boto3.client('s3').list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket,Prefix=folder)
    conn = boto3.client('s3')
    for key in conn.list_objects(Bucket=bucket,Prefix=folder)['Contents']:
        file_name = list(key['Key'])
        print(''.join(file_name))
    fileCount = objs['KeyCount']
    fileCount = fileCount - 1
    print(fileCount)
    if fileCount >= 5:
        print('the files are present,going to send notification') #here add the glue trigger
    else:
        print("None")
```

Comment: This is actually not needed and can be handled in the new configuration of the glue Job trigger. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-jobs-trigger.html#aws-glue-api-jobs-trigger-EventBatchingCondition